# Ignoring uncaught error Error: Server terminated early with status 3221225477

Tags: angular, google-chrome, protractor, docker-container

I am running into an error while running ng e2e on protractor scripts. The scripts are run on docker container. Latest version of chrome is installed along with Nodejs. BTW the container is windows. Please advise. Let me know if any additional logs are required.

Error: Ignoring uncaught error Error: Server terminated early with status 3221225477

Here is my browser capabilities:

```
 capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    loggingPrefs: {
      browser: 'INFO',
      performance: 'ALL'
    },
    chromeOptions: {
      perfLoggingPrefs: {
        enableNetwork: true
      },
      prefs: { 'safebrowsing.enabled': 'false' },
      args: [
        '--incognito',
        '--start-maximized',
        '--headless','--no-sandbox','--disable-gpu',
        '--window-size=1920,1080',
        '--ignore-certificate-errors'
      ],
      excludeSwitches: ['enable-automation'],
      useAutomationExtension: false
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options.

1. Add this `'--disable-dev-shm-usage'` in chromeOptions args.
   or
2. mount /dev/shm from your host to docker container.

I would recommend to use second option.